# Determine the constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ that satisfy the following equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{19}{x^3+x^2-14x+6} = \frac{A}{x-3}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+4x-2}$$

The answer is $A = 1, B = -1, C =-7$.

Comment: The answer is wrong. For $x=0$ you get positive equals negative.

Comment: @GitGud sorry, C = -7 not 7

Comment: @GitGud even if it's wrong could you show me the steps on solving such a problem?

Comment: Pretty simple: Put in 3 values for x get 3 equations solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is known as [partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

First, note that $x^3+x^2-14x+6=(x-3)(x^2+4x-2)$, so the first step should be clear:

If $$\frac{19}{x^3+x^2-14x+6} = \frac{A}{x-3}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+4x-2}=\frac{A(x^2+4x-2)+(Bx+C)(x-3)}{x^3+x^2-14x+6},$$
then we have that

$A(x^2+4x-2)+(Bx+C)(x-3)=19+0*(x^2)+0*(x)$

for this to be true, we require that $-2A-3C=19$, $B+A=0$, and that $4A-3B+C=0$. The intuition here, is that all of the coefficients for $x^2$, $x$, and $1$ should line up on both sides of the equality.

From this linear system, we can deduce that

$$\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 & -3\\ 1 & 1 & 0\\ 4 & -3 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}A \\ B \\C \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}19 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

(Alternatively you can solve the $3\times3$ system of linear equations using standard methods.)

From here, you determine the solutions:

$$\begin{bmatrix}A \\ B \\C \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ -7\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you! I actually arrived at the second step there but I did not know I could equal them to 0.

Comment: Absolutely no problem :) It's good that you had fiddled around a bit, otherwise my answer may have been a little opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Since the identity holds for all $x$, you can get the values of $A$, $B$, $C$ by judicious choice of $x$.

- Multiply both sides of the identity by $(x-3)$, then substitute $x=3$. Since $x^3+x^2-14x+6=(x-3)(x^2+4x-2)$, this gives $\frac{19}{19}=A$, so $A=1$.
- Multiply both sides by $x$ and let $x\to\infty$. This gives $0=A+B$, so $B=-1$.
- Set $x=0$. This gives $\frac{19}6=-\frac A3-\frac C2$, so $C=-7$.